# Variable not getting expanded

Tags: perl, subroutine

Variable not getting substituted

Even after defining the 2 variable explicitly it's not getting substituted

```
sub updatekey{
    my $key_url = File::Spec->catfile($dir. "/keys/cert.key.$label.$type")        
    $eol = '';
    open(FILE, $key_url) or die "$!";
    my $key_file;
    while (read(FILE, $buf, 60*57)) {
        $keyfile = $key_file . encode_base64($buf,$eol);
    }
}
```

Open FILE getting failed because $type is not getting substituted. if I modify the line as below

```
my $key_url = File::Spec->catfile($dir. "/keys/cert.key.$label.pem")
```

it's working fine.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. I don't see where you define `$label` or `$type`. Please [edit] your question, format your code as code, and provide a [mcve]. You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Please show the code where `$type` is defined

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, it is getting substituted. Perhaps not with the value you intend, but you provided no information to help you with that.  See [mcve]

Comment: This might be independent of your issue, but note that you have a dot (string concatenation), rather than a comma, in your args list to catfile. So that function call isn't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic debugging.

Add this to your code as the first lines in the subroutine:

```
if (defined $type) {
  print "\$type is undefined\n";
} else {
  print "\$type is '$type'\n";
}
```

That way, you'll see exactly what value `$type` has just before you try to use it. I expect you'll see either "$type is undefined" or "$type is ''".

Your problem then becomes finding where `$type` is supposed to be set and working out why that isn't happening.

Two other pieces of advice:

- When writing a Perl program, it's always a good idea to have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code (near the top of the file) as they will find a large number of basic programming errors.
- When programming in any language, you should ensure that any subroutine only uses variables that are passed in at parameters or variables that are declared within the subroutine. Using global variables (as you seem to be doing here) makes your code less portable and harder to debug.